# Develop a new Opendaylight application which includes nc-mount

Tags: opendaylight

I'm new to develop Opendaylight(ODL) applications. I'm planning to develop our application, which interacts Netconf devices. So, I expect using **nc-mount**. However, I can't develop application now because there are some problems.

I've tried the follows so far:

1. I tried the [tutorial](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html). I made the example application following this, but I didn't know how to install **nc-mount** into startup-archetype.
   And currently, I tried this tutorial again after Neon released, but the build was failed.
   I think that maybe there is some trouble on the repository now.
2. In order to know the behavior of **nc-mount**, I confirmed [netconf repository](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/netconf). I've checked out **release/fluorine-sr2** and the build succeeded. I've confirmed existing of **netconf-connector-all**. But **Netconf testtool** was not worked correctly... So that, I cannot confirm the behavior of **nc-mount**...
   Also, I don't know how to import own application into ODL controller even if I've read this [document](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netconf/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide.html).

Questions are the follows:

About the development of applications:

- Do you know recommended ways to develop the application including **nc-mount**?
- Or, If you know the proper documents, please let me know...

About Netconf testtool:

- Have you had the same experience when you use Netconf testtool?

  - The build succeeded. But probably the tool was not worked correctly.
- If you have some solution to solve this problem, please let me know...
- Netconf testtool starting logs and ssh connection logs are the follows:

```sh
$ java -jar netconf-testtool-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar &
[1] 13108
15:22:07.155 [main] INFO  o.o.n.t.tool.NetconfDeviceSimulator - Starting 1, SSH simulated devices starting on port 17830
15:22:07.199 [main] INFO  o.o.n.t.tool.NetconfDeviceSimulator - Custom module loading skipped.
15:22:08.254 [main] INFO  o.o.n.t.tool.NetconfDeviceSimulator - using OperationsProvider.
15:22:08.543 [main] INFO  o.a.s.c.u.s.b.BouncyCastleSecurityProviderRegistrar - getOrCreateProvider(BC) created instance of org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
15:22:08.684 [main] WARN  io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap - Unknown channel option 'SO_BACKLOG' for channel '[id: 0x10ab3fa2]'
15:22:08.875 [main] INFO  o.o.n.t.tool.NetconfDeviceSimulator - All simulated devices started successfully from port 17830 to 17830

$ ssh admin@localhost -p 17830 -s netconf
15:22:30.832 [sshd-netconf-ssh-server-nio-group-thread-1] WARN  o.a.s.s.session.ServerSessionImpl - exceptionCaught(ServerSessionImpl[null@/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:48026])[state=Opened] SshException: sendKexInit() no resolved signatures available
15:22:30.835 [sshd-netconf-ssh-server-nio-group-thread-1] INFO  o.a.s.s.session.ServerSessionImpl - Disconnecting(ServerSessionImpl[null@/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:48026]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_HOST_KEY_NOT_VERIFIABLE - sendKexInit() no resolved signatures available
Received disconnect from ::1 port 17830:9: sendKexInit() no resolved signatures available
Disconnected from ::1 port 17830
```

If you need more information to answer my questions, please let me know.

I really expect using Opendaylight, but it is too difficult to develop own ODL apps. I'm confused because there are so many documents... However, I'll be earnest to ODL App development.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question about netconf test tool, you can check this recent thread: https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/netconf-dev/2019-April/002116.html

Comment: Thanks! It is very helpful for us, and we can start test tool now. BTW,  currently, we can not generate startup-archetype... I saw the [repository](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/) but couldn't find the correct archetype-version because I couldn't find group ID="org.opendaylight.archetypes" and artifact ID="opendaylight-startup-archetype". Do you know anything about this problem?